# Creating a UIButton programmatically on iPhone X but safe area issue

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios11, cgrect, iphone-x

I created a `UIButton` in the middle of a `TabBarController` but it is not correctly displayed on the iPhone X because of its safe areas in the bottom of the phone.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    //Frame mic button
    micButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 62, y: self.view.bounds.height - 94, width: 124, height: 124)
    micButton.layer.cornerRadius = 62        
}
```

[image]

What is the correct way for drawing this `UIButton` without touching the safe areas.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't jibe at all with anything related to auto layout. (1) Why are you setting frame values? This is likely the *most* important thing. (2) Safe areas typically - maybe even absolutely - imply constraints. Where are they? By this I mean to ask... (3) A "safe area" for iPhone X - and by definition, iOS 11 - means `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. So why are you showing code that doesn't use this or any other *auto layout constraint*?

Comment: @dfd thats true but i never did layouts programmatically if you know a good programmatic constrains guide or tutorial that would be great. Plus i thought there would be different view properties that i don’t know that calculates the view frame starting from the safe zones. Or is it all dependent on the constraints?

Comment: Let me post a programmatic answer. It may be incomplete or even worthless. But hopefully it's neither and will help. (And if it's missing something, post a comment and I'll edit.)

Comment: @dfd that would be great. I can use it at least as a guide line.

Answer (score 1):

Safe zones, specifically a `safeAreaLayoutGuide`, relates to constraints.

There are various ways to code auto layout constraints (Visual Format Layout or VFL, explicit - and wordy - `NSLayoutConstraints`) but my preference is to use "layout anchors".

The basic idea for any layout is *position* and *size*. Give something a width/height, and x/y axis value and you've got it. Pretty much like frames.

So the basic "anchor" way of laying out this:

```
micButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 62, y: self.view.bounds.height - 94, width: 124, height: 124)
```

Would be this:

```
let micButton = UIButton()
micButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -94).isActive = true
micButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
micButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
micButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -62).isActive = true
```

Some notes:

- Yes, you do not dictate a frame. In fact, you just initialize things when possible.
- Since you aren't using IB, you need to set the auto resize mask flag to false. This is something even the most experienced developers sometimes forget. (Doing so usually means you have "unexpected" results ranging from not seeing something to seeing it misplaced.)
- I've set the bottom or Y axis, the width and height, and finally the X axis.

While it's more code than using a frame, what you gain is consistency across screen sizes.

But you want more - you need to code for iPhone X safe zones. You have two tools Apple has given you: `layoutMarginsGuide` and `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. The former was introduced in iOS 9 (along with the more simple `layoutGuide` and layout anchors) while the latter was introduced in iOS 11.

*[My assumption, probably a safe one, is that all iPhone X devices will run iOS 11 or later. Since a "safe area" is really only needed for this device, the following is what you need.]*

Margins work with *all* devices for leading/trailing (or horizontal) edges. They also work for top/bottom (or vertical) edges too. But for iPhone X you need to be concerned with a different top/bottom, thus the "safe area".

```
let layoutGuideTop = UILayoutGuide()
let layoutGuideBottom = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideTop)
view.addLayoutGuide(layoutGuideBottom)
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
view.addLayoutGuide(margins)
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
} else {
    layoutGuideTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    layoutGuideBottom.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

The code snippet above will yield the correct top/bottom margin variables (`layoutGuideTop` and `layoutGuideBottom`) based on the iOS version. From there you can adjust your bottom anchor to:

```
micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: laytouGuideBottom, constant: -94).isActive = true
```

Which should set `micButton` to be 94 points above the bottom safe area.

Here's a few links that should help you with layout anchors and guides:

[Layout Anchors](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/)

[Layout Guides](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/)

[Safe Area Layout Guides](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/)

**EDIT:**

One last note about constraints. Since you aren't relying on frame values, all of this code is best placed in `viewDidLoad`, because the layout engine will determine everything appropriately (and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may be called more than once).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**Add in UITabViewController's class**

```
micButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(micButton)
  if #available(iOS 11, *) {
       let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
       micButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
       micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       micButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
       micButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true

  } else {
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: micButton, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: micButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
       micButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
       micButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dfd guidance this was the way i did it as a work around. I just checked if the phone using the app has the same screen size as iPhoneX and i just changed in the constraints.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Frame mic button
    micButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 62, y: self.view.bounds.height - 94, width: 124, height: 124)
    micButton.layer.cornerRadius = 62
    micButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    micButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "micIcon"), for: .normal)
    //Add to tabbar view
    self.view.insertSubview(micButton, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)


    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
            //iPhoneX Device
            micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            micButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
            micButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
            micButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tabBar.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        } else {
            //Not an iPhoneX Device
            micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
            micButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
            micButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124).isActive = true
            micButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tabBar.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }

    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code help you to solve your problem.

```
micButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation what your code does?

Comment: use to solve this problem Normally we use view.bottomAnchor but this problem we want to use safeAreaLayoutGuide.